# Camera View Stucks on UI after capturing barcode successfully

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing

I am having issue in **Xamarin.Forms.Android** with below scenario:

I am testing and able to reproduce issue in ZXing Xamarin.Forms [sample](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile).

In Samples -> FormsSample.Droid:
I have created copy of `CustomScanPage.cs` and using copied page to scan barcode again after scanning successfully in first `CustomScanPage`.

I am not doing `PopAsync` with first `CustomScanPage`.

My issue is when I go to second `CustomScanPage`(say `CustomScanPage1`) I can see camera view is stucked to old captured barcode image. Although it captures barcode in background but UI is not updated as I can not see camera preview.

Means, Issue arises when I have already `CustomScanPage` in backstack.

Note: **This happens in case of android only**, working fine in iOS.

**UPDATE 1:**

Looks like issue is in `this.Holder`, it is common. May be Old View is displayed on SurfaceView due to this case. Also in Xamarin.Forms we are using things in portable which are common across platforms. So one `Activity` is used for every 
`Page`.

**This is simple scenario**: Page stucks right after you completed scan, that same stucked page is displayed on next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this conclusion finally, SurfaceDestroyed event is not fired from Xamarin.Android ZXing library. It is called when Page is Poped out. (Additionally in iOS ShutDownCamera code surface view is destroyed, which is not present in android StopScanning method.)

So, I made a workaround of removing previous page from stack and maintained it in somewhere, after scanning from next page, and going back inserted that persisted page again. So, I am just taking care that only one page which contains scanner will be there in stack.